# Is there a function in PyTorch for matrix left division?

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression

MATLAB has the backslash "\" operator. SciPy has "lsqr." Does PyTorch have an equivalent operator that solves systems of linear equations?

Specifically, I need to solve the matrix equation for `A*X=B` for `A`, and I need autograd to be able to backpropagate error through the operation.

Comment: This: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.solve.html?

Comment: I think I need a more general function. `torch.solve` solves for `X`, but I need to be able to solve for `A`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `\` operator in *Python*. The closest you will get to is *Scipy*'s implementation: [`scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html).

You can either use

- [`torch.solve`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.solve.html) to solve linear equations of shape `AX=B`
- [`torch.lsrsq`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.lstsq.html) to

  - solve the least-squares problem `min ||AX-B||_2` (if `A.size(0) >= A.size(1)`) *or*
  - solve the least-norm problem `min ||X||_2` such that `AX=B` (if `A.size(0) < A.size(1)`)
    ​

---

For solving `XA=B` you would use the transposed matrices:

```
def lsqrt(A, B):
    XT, _ = torch.solve(B.T, A.T)
    return XT.T
```

Comment: I think I need a more general function. `torch.solve` and `torch.lstsq` solve for `X`, but I need to be able to solve for `A`.